# for loop over character array gives unexpected "("

Tags: bash, scripts

I am a bloody beginner in bash scripting and I am sorry if the following is very simple. 
The error I get is:

`4: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

I am basically trying to run the following in bash on a Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS server:

```
#!/bin/bash

### Positions
declare -a POS=("01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "16" "17" "18")

### Timeslices
declare -a ZSPOS_01=("1" "3" "4" "5")
declare -a ZSPOS_02=("1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "8" "9" "10" "11" "12" "31" "41" "51" "101")
declare -a ZSPOS_03=("1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "31" "41" "91")
declare -a ZSPOS_04=("1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "41" "51" "101")
declare -a ZSPOS_05=("2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "9" "10" "11" "51" "61" "101")
declare -a ZSPOS_06=("1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "8" "31" "51" "71")
declare -a ZSPOS_16=("1" "2" "3" "4" "11" "41")
declare -a ZSPOS_17=("1" "2" "3" "4" "11" "41")
declare -a ZSPOS_18=("1" "2" "3" "4")

for SCANPOSITION in ${POS[@]}
do
    for ZEITSCHNITT in ${ZSPOS_$SCANPOSITION[@]}
        do
            echo "Timeslice" $ZEITSCHNITT "in Position" $SCANPOSITION "!"
        done
done
```

Comment: Take a look at http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: `for ZEITSCHNITT in ${ZSPOS_$SCANPOSITION[@]}` should be `for ZEITSCHNITT in "$SCANPOSITION"`..Please post the full error message you are having..

Answer (score 1):

1. the `( unexpected` error indicates you're calling your script like `sh scriptname` instead of `bash scriptname` or, preferably, `chmod 755 scriptname; ./scriptname`
2. Dynamic array names are hard to work with in bash. You require a temporary variable to use with [indirect expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion).

   ```
   for SCANPOSITION in "${POS[@]}"
   do
       tmp="ZSPOS_${SCANPOSITION}[@]"

       for ZEITSCHNITT in "${!tmp}"    # note the "!"
       do
           echo "Timeslice $ZEITSCHNITT in Position $SCANPOSITION !"
       done
   done
   ```
3. You should always quote your `"$variables"` unless you know exactly why you want to leave the quotes off.
4. Also, get out of the habit of using `ALL_CAPS_VARS` -- some day you will [accidentally use `PATH`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310594/ls-not-found-after-running-read-path) and then wonder why your script is broken